# Alexa Skill To Retrieve an Image

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Right now my skill has two slots

- (1) detailNumber
- (2) pageNumber.

The skill correctly gets these slots and repeats them back to the user successfully.

However, I would like the skill to pull and image from an S3 bucket that has these slots as its filename (i.e. detailNumber-pageNumber.png). How can this be achieved?

```
class LaunchRequestHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
"""Handler for Skill Launch."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
    return ask_utils.is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    speak_output = "Welcome, to fabrication. What detail would you like to view?"
    reprompt_text = "Open detail 5 on LSF-900."

    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            .ask(reprompt_text)
            .response
    )
```

---

```
class OpenDetailIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
"""Handler for Open Detail Intent."""
def can_handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
    return ask_utils.is_intent_name("OpenDetailIntent")(handler_input)

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
    detailNumber = slots["detailNumber"].value
    pageNumber = slots["pageNumber"].value
    speak_output = 'Thanks, I will show you detail {detailNumber} on page LSF {pageNumber}.'.format(detailNumber=detailNumber, pageNumber=pageNumber)

    return (
        handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speak_output)
            # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
            .response
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you use s3 Alexa Hosted

1. Make sure your files are on the s3
2. [Create a presigned URL](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-media-files.html#media-python) :

Example >

```
from ask_sdk_model import ui
from utils import create_presigned_url

def handle(self, handler_input):
    # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
    image_url = create_presigned_url("Media/" + detailNumber + "-" + pageNumber +" .png")
```

utils.py (available in the scratch template on the developer console)

```
import logging
import os
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def create_presigned_url(object_name):
    """Generate a presigned URL to share an S3 object with a capped expiration of 60 seconds

    :param object_name: string
    :return: Presigned URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             region_name=os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_REGION'),
                             config=boto3.session.Config(signature_version='s3v4',s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
    try:
        bucket_name = os.environ.get('S3_PERSISTENCE_BUCKET')
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': bucket_name,
                                                            'Key': object_name},
                                                    ExpiresIn=60*1)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return None

    # The response contains the presigned URL
    return response
```

Make sure to use `Media` as default parent folder on Alexa hosted skills.

#### If you don't use s3 Alexa Hosted

Then you can either provide the path to the s3 directly or create signed URLS with proper permissions if the s3 is not public as mentioned above.